# How is the better way for route in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I do not know what is a better way for route files in NodeJS. Best explained, I've seen some examples in which people use methods and all is written in javascript, and another people use HTML documents ( *they use readfile method for read its HTML documents*).
okey really my question is, what use "fs" for do my website or only do a router and write all in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good that you asked for a **better way** and the not **best way** since that is easier to answer. The best way is always subjective lol.

I suggest that you use a NodeJS web application framework such as Express, Kraken, Sails, etc. This will allow you to write HTML templates naturally (they are called views in MVC terminology). After that, you just have to specify the views' routes/names in the controller and NodeJS will automatically serve them upon receiving a request.

Express Framework: http://expressjs.com/
Kraken: http://krakenjs.com/
Sails: sailsjs.org

Comment: really you've helped me, thank you for your answer, I did not know that. My reputation it's too low and I will be not able to vote "Useful" your answer excuse me.